# Как удалить из приватного docker репозитория

Tags: docker

На своем сервере был создан приватный репозиторий v2. Встала необходимость его почистить, т.е. удалить очень старые версии образов. В документации написано удалять вот так:

```
curl -v -X DELETE https://user:passwd@docker.my-rep.ru:5000/v2/bkf/sdf/manifests/1
```

И тут выдается ошибка:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"UNSUPPORTED","message":"The operation is unsupported."}]}
```

При этом команда GET при том же запросе выполняется на ура.

Подскажите куда копать ?

Comment: А в респонзе что, он же должен что-то отвечать?

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed.`  Теперь осталось узнать как его включить ? Я его настраивал без конфигурационного файла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через поиск нашел где храниться текущая настройка конфигурации registry

```
find / | grep config.yml
```

у меня это:

```
/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/c14810bbf0311d4d53261635ef75f425c725f7ad61e64f3e046cc1c46051da18/etc/docker/registry/config.yml
```

В этот файл добавляем 2-е строки:

```
version: 0.1
 log:
   fields:
     service: registry
 storage:
     cache:
         blobdescriptor: inmemory
     filesystem:
         rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
+    delete:
+      enabled: true
 http:
     addr: :5000
     headers:
         X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
 health:
   storagedriver:
     enabled: true
     interval: 10s
     threshold: 3
```

Удаление образа происходит по его digest, т.е. по
`sha256:7a36321d3ec343da43cc886d52011f5b8c822b1d474fb2cc397faf681a4136eb`

Я сумел найти этот параметр только, когда скачивал образ из репозитория и в конце выводился этот параметр.

Как другой вариант, нашел скрипт который удаляет образы в репозитории https://github.com/burnettk/delete-docker-registry-image

Перед его выполнением, необходимо указать, где находится репозиторий

```
export REGISTRY_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/docker/volumes/5126f8d31aa3a620a5e27694ce88cf67b21f3044bce0dc45066f64c354026d6d/_data/docker/registry/v2/
```

После этого можно запускать скрипт с указанием какой образ нужно удалить

```
delete_docker_registry_image --image bkf/sdf:1
```